# Undefined object cannot be read

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am doing a query of a mongo collection and the property I'm trying to access is not available since the object is apparently undefined. I am using callbacks so I'm not sure why it's trying to access a null object?

```
exports.checkPermissions = function(uname, pw){
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;
    console.log(uname + ", " + pw);

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/users', function(err, udb) {
        if(err) throw err;

        var targetcol = udb.collection('profiles');
        targetcol.find({username: uname, password: pw}, {permissions: 1}).toArray(function(err, results) {
            if( err || !results){
                console.log("error occured");
                response.redirect('/');
            }
            else {
                if (results[0].permissions == 'system admin'){
                    response.redirect('/adminDashboard');
                }
                else
                    response.redirect('/userDashboard');
            }
            udb.close();
        });
    });
}
```

The part that I'm getting an error is:

`if (results[0].permissions == 'system admin')`

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of undefined
```

Comment: What's the output of console.log(results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` will be a 0-length array when a matching user isn't found, so your `if` check in the callback needs to look like this instead:

```
if( err || !results.length){
    ...
```

You should probably use `findOne` instead of `find` for this type of query as it's a better fit for this use case and will result in simpler code.